# Docker Registry loosing Images data on restart

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Docker-registry image is started in local machine. Images that are built are able to be pushed to docker-registry. However, when we do the restart of the registry, the pushed images are lost and not retained.

Started the container with --always tag.

No Code

Expected result would be to retain the images in the registry even after a restart of the docker-registry.

Comment: Sorted. I was not using the volume.

Comment: I don't understand what approach you were using. Docker itself? Docker compose? I had the same problem with Docker Compose and I fixed, but indeed it's unclear to me whenever it's fine to add an answer under here, since there is not any detail in the question. Thanks for clarification, even if old question.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a directory on the host file system to store the images during registry downtime, and bindmount that into the registry upon restart.

So in your `docker run` for the registry, you need this:

`-v /registry-storage:/var/lib/registry`

you can name the lefthand directory anything you like. You must call the righthand side of the colon `/var/lib/registry`

Comment: Note that if you discover your error before stopping the initial container, you can retrieve the data with `docker cp <container id>:/var/lib/registry /registry-storage` before restarting it as explained above.